# Sending Castle Proxy from NHibernate with MassTransit over MSMQ causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, msmq, castle, masstransit

I'm trying to send a message with MassTransit over MSMQ.  The message contains two properties which are types obtained from an NHibernate query and contain Castle Proxies (for lazy loading).

If I send the message (using `bus.Endpoint.Send(msg)`) with the proxies as part of the message I generate a StackOverflowException.  If I don't assign these two properties, and leave them null, the message fires through the queue without issue.

Is this just the way it is, or am I doing something wrong with the MSMQ/MassTransit setup?

If not, would I need to use something like AutoMapper to get rid of these proxies?

Comment: Do you get this StackOverflowException when trying to access these lazy loaded properties? Or just by sending the messsage through the bus?

Comment: Just by sending the message.  Happens on the producer side before hitting MSMQ.

Comment: can you create a stand-alone testcase to reproduce this?

Comment: anyway, yes, I'd map it to a DTO before sending it through the wire.

Comment: Yah - mapping it to a DTO with AutoMapper helped, however ended up with NHibernate weirdness on the other end (since the session was in a different process).  Needed an architectural re-think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely an exception based upon the dynamic proxies generated and the serializer being used. I assume it's the default XML serializer? I would post an issue to the github page for MT so we can look at this: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit

These messages should be consider contracts for decoupling between processes. Using NHibernate entities, these services become coupled with more than just the messages as a DB change could effect the other consumers. Ideally you would always map this to another object before passing it along.

Is there a reason why you aren't just `bus.Publish(msg)` instead of sending directly to the Bus' endpoint? You could join the MT mailing list and discuss this in more detail: http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss

I hope this helps!